# Querying on the result of another query

Tags: sql

I want the result of the query in the brackets to be queried again. I referred a few post in stack and came up with the below query. But somehow the second query(the one outside the bracket) ain't working. Error says there is incorrect syntax near the second 'group'. Can someone please help.

```
select CourseID, count(CourseID)
from
    (select CustomisationID, CourseID , Count(CourseID)
     from tblFilter
     where CustomisationID in (43, 51) 
     group by CourseID, CustomisationID) 
group by CourseID
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And what is the ***exact*** error message?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? That query is a bit "odd".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select M.CourseID, count(M.CourseID) from
(
   select CustomisationID, CourseID , Count(CourseID) AS Cnt from tblFilter where CustomisationID in (43,51) 
    group by CourseID, CustomisationID
)M 
group by M.CourseID
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set alias for subquery. Try Something like this:

```
select CourseID, count(CourseID) 
from
(
    select CustomisationID, CourseID , Count(CourseID) AS Cnt
    from tblFilter 
    where CustomisationID in (43,51) 
    group by CourseID, CustomisationID
) AS TMP
group by CourseID
```

Comment: ANSI SQL doesn't require table alias here, but some products do.

Comment: May be problem in Aggregation in subquery? MS SQL require column name for each column.